# webpack not generating css file

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

Implementing [webpack asset management tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) .but webpack is not generating css file in output path

**webpack.config.js**

```
const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpeg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**index.js**

```
  import './style.css';
  import Icon from './yo1.jpg';

  function component() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    element.innerHTML = 'hello webpack'
    element.classList.add('hello');

    var myIcon = new Image();
    myIcon.src = Icon;

    element.appendChild(myIcon);

    return element;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(component());
```

[image]

> **Problem**

images are nicely created in build folder

but

it does not creates style.css in build folder , what wrong i am doing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

webpack does not create separate css files. It get's bundled with the javascript and is injected into the DOM as `style` tags by webpack bootstrap code.

If you want to create separate css file, you can use the ExtractTextPlugin - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`ExtractTextPlugin` is **deprecated** try https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // all options are optional
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
      ignoreOrder: false, // Enable to remove warnings about conflicting order
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: '../',
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```